# Phenolphthalein indicator spill onto skin

Tags: everyday-chemistry, toxicity

I was using a phenolphthalein indicator to test the acidity of some 0.1 M HCl. I was using the pipette to draw the phenolphthalein indicator out of the tiny jar but it wasn't working, so I thought that it might not have much left in it, so I tilted it at an angle to try and get the remaining indicator. However it turns out the pipette wasn't working and it was full and a couple of millilitres spilt out, some spilt onto my right index finger, but most of it spilt onto the bench. I immediately rinsed my finger under running water for about 7-10 seconds. Just wondering if it'll have any negative effects. I'm pretty sure it was 99.9% methanol and 0.08% phenolphthalein measured in weight.

Comment: _Sigh_ At least it's not about methanol this time...

Comment: It was during class. We didn't receive the MSDS or gloves. We were just using it as an indicator in an experiment and the dropper didn't work so I automatically tilted it as I thought there wasn't much left in the bottom. Turns out it was full and the dropper was faulty, so a bit got on my hand and on the bench. I immediately rinsed my hand  under water for about 10 seconds. We were wearing safety glasses and everything but I guess I just was a bit clumsy. This is why you get enough sleep at night.

Comment: Also it was a minuscule amount of phenolphthalein in an ethanolic solution.

Answer (score 3):

- Didn't you receive the SDS for phenolphtalein (or its methanolic/ethanolic solutions)?
- Weren't you given instructions on how to handle it?
- Didn't you wear suitable gloves in addition to your safety goggles?

Back in the days, phenolphthalein was apparently used as a laxative. This is no longer recommended!

However, the current GHS classification is as follows:

> Germ cell mutagenicity, Category 2; H341
>   Carcinogenicity, Category 1B; H350
>   Reproductive toxicity, Category 2; H361f

(*cited from the [GESTIS database](http://www.dguv.de/ifa/gestis/gestis-stoffdatenbank/index-2.jsp)*)

To my knowledge, [phenolphtalein](https://echa.europa.eu/substance-information/-/substanceinfo/100.000.914) is on the REACH Candidate list of SVHC (*substances of very high concern*) since 2011.

My suggestion is:

1. Contact a physician.
2. Report the exposition to your supervisors.

Comment: If every time sth like this happens physicians would be contacted, they would ask about pay rise ;D

Comment: @Mithoron It depends on who you are and where you work. As a student at a university, nobody gives a *f-word* ;-). In a company with a stricter regulations, dermal exposition to CMR compounds, particularly when juvenile apprentices without gloves are involved, can get the supervisors in deep sh*t. Exposition of workers to CMR and TOST materials has to be recorded. According to current German laws, the records have to be kept for  40 years after the last exposition!